# How to send object from one to another view?

Tags: ios, xcode, saslidemenu

I have implemented [SASlideMenu](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/saslidemenu) for side menu and is excellent everything except one thing. I don't know how to send object.

Here is switching view happening:

```
-(void) switchToContentViewController:(UIViewController*) content{

    CGRect bounds = self.view.bounds;
    if (selectedContent) {


        //Animate out the currently selected UIViewController
        [UIView animateWithDuration:kSlideOutInterval delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            selectedContent.view.frame = CGRectMake(bounds.size.width,0,bounds.size.width,bounds.size.height);
        } completion:
         ^(BOOL completed) {

             [selectedContent willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
             [selectedContent.view removeFromSuperview];
             [selectedContent removeFromParentViewController];

             content.view.frame = CGRectMake(bounds.size.width,0,0,bounds.size.height);
             [self addChildViewController:content];
             [self.view addSubview:content.view];
             [UIView animateWithDuration:kSlideInInterval delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
                 content.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,bounds.size.width,bounds.size.height);

             } completion:^(BOOL completed){
                 selectedContent = content;
                 [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                 [self.shield removeFromSuperview];
             }];
         }];
    }else{
        [self addChildViewController:content];
        [self.view addSubview:content.view];
        content.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,bounds.size.width,bounds.size.height);
        selectedContent = content;
        [self.shield removeFromSuperview];
        [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    }
}
```

and what I want is here to get identifier (NSString) (that I will know how to solve) and then send to this new view controller which will be open.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subclass of UIViewController instead of the stock UIViewController class for your "content" view controller. On this subclass, you can add a

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *stringForContentView;
```

Then, just above the line where you add the "content" view controller as a child of your current view controller,

```
content.stringForContentView = @"A string that you already have";
```

Comment: Just make a new file. Enter a name (something like ContentViewController). Select UIViewController as the superclass. You will get ContentViewController.h and ContentViewController.m in your project navigator and you can customize as you please form there. Then,  wherever you are calling switchToContentViewController, make sure you pass it an instance of ContentViewController, not a generic UIViewController. (Probably also change the method to only accept ContentViewController as an argument).

Comment: Sorry but obviously I'm noob. Can you please  write me where exactly and how add in swtich and how to call later this variable? THank you very much for your time

Comment: you already have your switchToContentViewController method somewhere in your code. If it's already bringing up your new view controller then it's fine where it is. Just make sure that that new view controller is a subclass of UIViewController with a property (I called it stringForContentView but you can call it anything you like). Then, as I mentioned in my answer, just above [self addChildViewController:content];, add content.stringForContentView = @"A string that you already have";. If you need to use the variable in the instance of ContenViewController, it's just self.stringForContentView.

Comment: I understand now but that is imposible because of this: -(void) switchToContentViewController:(UIViewController*) content{
"content" is defined here, it doesen't exists extra file for that UIVIewCotronller (content)

Comment: No, content is not defined there. Your method name only specifies the kind of argument the method takes. The view controller has to be instantiated and then passed to that method. Not sure what you mean by "it doesnen't exists extra file for that...". When you create a subclass, Xcode generates header and implementation files for you which you then add your customization to.